# HTML/CSS center content within panel--JSFiddle Included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y8bhc1w7/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: #CEECF5;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul id="sortable">
          <li class="ui-state-default">p</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">e</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">r</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">r</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">o</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
#sortable { 
list-style-type: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
width: 1250px; 
}
#sortable li { 
margin: -8px 8px 3px 0; 
padding: 5px; 
float: left; 
width: 40px; 
height: 40px; 
font-size: .8em; 
text-align: center; 
font-weight:bold; 
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $(" #sortable ").sortable({axis: "x", containment: "window"});
});
```

I'm trying to center the letter tiles 'p', 'e', 'r', etc... relative to the panel the tiles are inside of. Any thoughts on how to best do this?

Comment: center horizontally, vertically would be nice too though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s7xp1amg/)**.

I used `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` on the `li`s and `text-align: center` on `#sortable`.